# Android tcpip ADB session disconnects when accessory is attached

Tags: android, adk

I am developing an ADK application using Windows 7 x64, API 15 with a target of an Acer Tab A100 running Android 4.0.3 and an Arduino with a USB shield.  The tablet is not rooted.

I am able to successfully setup ADB to run over tcpip using the following command in a Windows command shell:

adb tcpip 5555
adb connect X.X.X.X

I then disconnect the usb cable from the Windows 7 PC and connect it to the Arduino.  The Arduino is running the ADK code and the tablet prompts to launch my application.  The application launches and runs fine.  However, when the Android application launches the ADB session terminates and I have to re-execute the adb connect command to re-establish it.

This doesn't seem like it should be happening.  Does anyone have any thoughts how to fix it?

Thanks,

digitalhack

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

ADB server can be started from android ADK based application, it will communicate with firmwate in the Arduino.I developed one project using ADB communication with Arduino, work fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to use ADB for app communication over USB. I'm deep into this right now and am trying to get openAccessory to work for this exact purpose (communicating with Arduino). openAccessory causes the Android device to operate in "device" or "slave" mode, permitting the Arduino to be run in "host" or "master" mode. Since the USB host is the one that powers the USB bus, this permits the Arduino and its (presumably) more powerful power supply to power the Android tablet rather than the other way around.

Read up on openAccessory mode in the Android API, and report back on your results!